# Split column maintaining empty values between delimiter R

Tags: r

How could I split this column (the dots represent additional values):

```
annotation

gene1|allele1|effect1|x1|...... 
gene2|||x2|......
```

into several different columns:

```
gene    allele    effect     x    .     .     .
gene1   allele1   effect1    x1   .     .     . 
gene2   NA        NA         x2   .     .     .
```

I tried:

```
list<-strsplit(as.character(df$annotation), '|')
```

The problem is that it returns a list with different dimensions, because it is not counting the empty spaces between two `|`. So, then, when I do:

```
new_df<-as.data.frame(list)
```

I get this error:

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows

So, how can sprintf transform count empty spaces between separators as NA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```r
stringr::str_split(df$annotation, '|', fixed = TRUE, simplify = TRUE)
```

You also have `tstrsplit` from `data.table` package:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, tstrsplit(annotation, "|", fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSPlit(df, 'annotation', '|')
```